# In Wordpress normally MySite.com/?p=795 redirects to MySite.com/Complete_URL/. Currently it's not working in my site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

In Wordpress normally **MySite.com/?p=795** redirects to **MySite.com/Complete_URL/**. Currently it's not working in my site...

Any idea why and how to fix it?

For example this site redirects to his long URL: https://flores.travel/?p=381

But this one don't: https://www.optimizatuvida.com/?p=795

Why?

Comment: go to Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks from Common Settings check one of options( besides first one, because it shows site as www.site.com/?p=1 ), after click Save Changes

Comment: I'm already using the third option... And no look. The permalinks work correctly, but the urls with p dont..
For example this site redirects: https://flores.travel/?p=381
But this one don't: https://www.optimizatuvida.com/?p=795
Why?

Comment: so, you want to redirect pages with query strings like `?p=some_id` to their user friendly structure? first, provide your `.htaccess` file by adding into your question